# Flurry USER ACQUISITION REPORTS with Android

Tags: android, tracking, flurry

i builded a Android App. For tracking i use flurry.
Now i want to build campaigns for partners. So i made own 
campaigns in flurry with own channels. I get url's for the partner 
like this: http://ad.apps.fm/{LONG STRING}

In the USER ACQUISITION Section from Flurry i see the clicks but i never
see the installs.

So i looked into the Flurry_3.2.2.jar and found the class com.flurry.android.InstallReceiver.
So i thought maybe i have to use that. For the campaignInstall i have my own 
broadcast receiver. So do i have to do this in the onReceive Method of my receiver?

new InstallReceiver().onReceive(context,intent);

I found nothing in the documentation.

Thanks,

Marc

Answer (score 0):

It seems this add.apps.fm urls doesn't work (at least on PC) — for android particularly.

Comment: The urls work fine. Just the tracking of the installs do not work